# keras dqn agent expecting more dimentions

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, reinforcement-learning

I have built a custom environment based on the openAI gym on which I aim to train a DQN agent.

In this environment, each observation space is one row, and 75 columns, and so

```
env.observation_space.shape

(75,)
```

When I build a model, I use the following:

```
def build_model(states, actions):
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(Dense(75, activation = 'relu', input_dim = 75))
    model.add(Dense(75, activation = 'relu'))
    model.add(Dense(actions, activation = 'relu'))
    return model
```

With the output shape of the first layer (none, 75) and the output shape of the final layer (none, 3) for each of the three possible actions.

In building my agent I use:

```
def build_agent(model, actions):
    policy = BoltzmannQPolicy()
    memory = SequentialMemory(limit=50000, window_length=1)
    dqn = DQNAgent(model=model, memory=memory, policy=policy, 
                  nb_actions=actions, nb_steps_warmup=10, target_model_update=1e-2)
    return dqn
```

However, fitting the agent throws the following error:

```
dqn = build_agent(model, actions)
dqn.compile(Adam(lr=1e-3), metrics=['mae'])
dqn.fit(env, nb_steps=50000, visualize=False, verbose=1)

Error when checking input: expected dense_58_input to have 2 dimensions, but got array with shape (1, 1, 75)
```

I don't understand how an extra dimension has been expected, given my data observations are 75 columns. Do I need to reshape my input or re-define the input layer of my model?

Comment: What library are you using for the DQNAgent, SequentialMemory, BoltzmannPolicy, etc.? I guess this might be related to how networks are initialised within that library using the gym.observation_space attribute in the environment.

Comment: currently using rl.agents. I fixed this problem using a flatten layer as the first later.

Comment: Could you please share your entire code? It seems like you are using relu in your last layer, which seems incorrect.

Answer (score 1):

From the comment section for the benefit of the community.

> currently using `rl.agents`. I fixed this problem using a flatten layer
> as the first layer.

Comment: Aha, and how exactly did the flatten layer solve the problem? I would still expect to start with a Dense layer or explicitly defining Input layer with input_shape which resembles the observation space.

Answer (score 0):

I see that you are using ‘relu’ activation in your last layer. DQN usually performs regression to predict q-values for each action and using a relu activation would prevent estimates from reaching their true values. If you could share your entire code, the community should be able to provide more insights.